# How to get internal stylesheet using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Anyone can please tell me How can I get an internal stylesheet using jQuery. I know how to get the style of hello class but I want to take the style of world class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  .hello{
   color: red;
  }
  .world{
   color: blue;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="hello">Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One more example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/ follow this..

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hello{
            color: red;
        }
        .world{
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="hello">Hello</p> 
    <p class="world">world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You define as .hello class but .world class is not declare how could it response both color in a one class attribute

Based on Jquery You refer this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

 <p class="hello">Hello world!</p>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

    var n = $(".hello").length;

    if (n < 2) {
        $(".hello").css("color", "red");
       $(".hello").css("background", "blue");

    } 
    else {
        $("body").css("color", "orange");
    }

});

</script>
```

Check Below Link [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default)

Comment: Above link for practice u paste my code and check once...